# GAE unicode character gets encoded to utf-8 bytes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, utf-8

In my app I'm accepting text from user inputs where users often paste text from microsoft word.

A good example being the apostrophe **’**, which for some reason gets converted to **=E2=80=99** when posting to my handler in google app engine. I've tried a number of confused ways to prevent this and I'm quite happy to simple remove these characters, some of these methods work in plain python but not in app engine.

here's some of what I've tried:

```
problem_string = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','', problem_string)# trying to remove it
problem_string = problem_string.encode( "utf-8" )# desperation...
problem_string = "".join((c if ord(c) < 128 else '' for c in problem_string))# trying to just remove the thing
problem_string = unicode(problem_string, "utf8")# probably fails since its already unicode
```

... where I'm trying to capture the string including **’** and then later save it to the ndb datastore as a StringProperty(). Except for the last option, the apsotrophe example gets converted to **=E2=80=99**.

If I could save the apostrophe type character and display it again that would be great, but simply removing it would also serve my needs.

*Edit - the following:

```
experience = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', experience)
```

seems to work fine on the dev server, and successfully removes the offending apostrophe.

Also what may be an issue is that the POST fields are going through the blobstore, so: blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler, which I think may being causing some problems.

I've really been bumping my head against this and I would really *really* appreciate an explanation from some clever stack-overflower...

Comment: Where are you seeing `=E2=80=99`? It is common for some file-handling tools to show you =NN hex-escapes for non-ASCII bytes, in which case that would be nothing to worry about. 0xE2, 0x80, 0x99 is the correct UTF-8 encoding for U+2018 Left Single Quotation Mark `’`. It is better to make your application handle non-ASCII characters correctly than to try to filter them out.

Comment: I agree, I think when using the blobstore request parameters are automatically escaped (or whatever the correct terminology is), so instead of preventing that I've just used the standard webapp2 request handler which deals with non-ASCII characters appropriately. Thanks for your response. Also =E2=80=99, was escaped immediately, so right in self.request.get("the param")

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've vaguely stumbled upon a solution.

It had something to do with the blobstore upload handler, I guess it was encoding/decoding unicode appropriately to account for weird file characters. So I modified the handler so that the image file is uploaded via google cloud storage instead of the blobstore and it seems to work fine, i.e. the **’** gets to the datastore as **’** instead of **=E2=80=99**

I won't accept my own answer for the next few days, maybe someone can clarify things better for future confused individuals.